# Get Highcharts width

Tags: jquery, highcharts, width, tooltip

I would like to get the current chart width, I have tried something like this:

```
chart.width
```

and

```
$(this).parent().width()
```

where chart is

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ ... })
```

But doesn't work...

**MORE INFO**

I would like to place an image (a helper) at the left of the exports buttons (responsive).

For the moment I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'area1',
            type: 'bar',
            events: {
                load: drawImages,

            }
         ...}
      })
    })
```

And

```
function drawImages() {
    var chart = this;
    x = chart.plotRight - 50

    chart.renderer.image('/assets/faq.png', x, 0, 20, 20)

    .attr({
        zIndex: 100,
        title: "My title for displaying a tooltip"
    })
    .css({
        cursor: 'pointer'
    })
    .add();   
    };
```

But the images appears at the left side of the chart (using `plotRight`).

I know how to get the width of the div container of the graph ("area1"), but I like to have code more Object Oriented (because I have at least 5 graphs per page).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I have find a solution, using the method "container":

```
$(chart.container).width()
```

This returns the current width of the chart.

Comment: In a chart event I had to refer to it as `$(this.container).width()`.  Probably obvious to everyone else, but I'm new ;-)

Answer (score 18):

In chart object you have access to chartWidth parameter, which keeps width of chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/7xNQL/1/

```
//callback
    function(chart){

                console.log(chart.chartWidth);

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the xAxis extreme.max and translate it to pixels. Something like (not tested):

```
Chart.xaxis[0].toPixels( chart xaxis[0].getExtremes().max )
```

It feels like there should be an easier way, but I guess I would have used the containing div width. Maybe you could use chart options to get the containing div I'd and get the width from that.

Comment: +1 for a possible solution (but I think that this one doesn't working for me, I get as size 14 when the graph width is 600), maybe I have find another "simpler" solution following your tip.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so my answer is just to provide more options for those who are checking this later.

If you want full width of chart:

```js
this.chart.chartWidth
```

If you want the chart xAxis width, without possible labels on the left (check image), you have two options:

```js
this.chart.plotWidth // or
this.chart.xAxis[0].width
```

[image]